# Textbox lose value after postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a group of text box that allows the user to automatically compute the gross amount. The computation is working but when the page post back all the text box value is gone. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Please see below my codes.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            Number.prototype.formatMoney = function (c, d, t) {
                var n = this,
                c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c,
                d = d == undefined ? "." : d,
                t = t == undefined ? "," : t,
                s = n < 0 ? "-" : "",
                i = String(parseInt(n = Math.abs(Number(n) || 0).toFixed(c))),
                j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
                return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
            };

        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(this).keyup(function () {

                $("input[name='txtbx_less']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_gross = $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_gross']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_less = parseFloat(txtbx_gross) * 0.15;

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_less)) {
                        $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_less']").eq(index).val(txtbx_less.formatMoney());
                    }

                });

                $("input[name='txtbx_net']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_gross = $("input[name='txtbx_ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_grossgross']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_less = $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_less']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_net = parseFloat(txtbx_gross) - parseFloat(txtbx_less);

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_net)) {
                        $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_net']").eq(index).val(txtbx_net.formatMoney());
                    }

                });

                $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_add']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net = $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_net']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add = parseFloat(txtbx_net) * 0.12;


                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_add)) {
                        $("input[name='ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_add']").eq(index).val(txtbx_add.formatMoney());

                    }

                });

                $("input[name='txtbx_billed']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net = $("input[name='txtbx_net']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add = $("input[name='txtbx_add']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_billed = parseFloat(txtbx_net) + parseFloat(txtbx_add);

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_billed)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_billed']").eq(index).val(txtbx_billed.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });


                $("input[name='txtbx_add1']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net1 = $("input[name='txtbx_net1']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add1 = parseFloat(txtbx_net1) * 0.12;


                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_add1)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_add1']").eq(index).val(txtbx_add1.formatMoney());
                    }

                });

                $("input[name='txtbx_billed1']").each(function (index) {
                    var txtbx_net1 = $("input[name='txtbx_net1']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_add1 = $("input[name='txtbx_add1']").eq(index).val().replace(/,/g, "");
                    var txtbx_billed1 = parseFloat(txtbx_net1) + parseFloat(txtbx_add1);

                    if (!isNaN(txtbx_billed1)) {
                        $("input[name='txtbx_billed1']").eq(index).val(txtbx_billed1.formatMoney());
                    }
                });



            });


        });
```

**Front-end**

```
    <table class = "billcomp">
        <tr>
        <td class = "prebiltd">GROSS AMOUNT :</td>
        <td class = "prebiltd">
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_gross" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
        <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999999g>.<00..99>" AllowMouseWheel="false"/>
        </dx:ASPxTextBox>
        </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td class = "prebiltd">LESS: 15% ASF :</td>
       <td class = "prebiltd">
       <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_less" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
       <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" AllowMouseWheel="false"/>
       </dx:ASPxTextBox>
       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td class = "prebiltd">NET AMOUNT :</td>
       <td class = "prebiltd">
       <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_net" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
       <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" AllowMouseWheel="false"/>
       </dx:ASPxTextBox>
       </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="chckbox_nonvat" runat="server" Text="NON-VAT"></asp:CheckBox>
       </td>
       </tr>

   <tr>
   <td class = "prebiltd">ADD 12% VAT :</td>
   <td class = "prebiltd">
   <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_add" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material" ClientInstanceName="txtbx_add">
   <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" AllowMouseWheel="false"/>
   </dx:ASPxTextBox>
   </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td class = "prebiltd">BILLED AMOUNT :</td>
   <td class = "prebiltd">
   <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_billed" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material">
   <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" AllowMouseWheel="false"/>
   </dx:ASPxTextBox>
   </td>
   </tr>

   </table>
```

**Back end codes**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 txtbx_gross.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_gross';   }"
        txtbx_less.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_less';   }"
        txtbx_net.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_net';   }"
        txtbx_add.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_add';   }"
        txtbx_billed.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_billed';   }"

        txtbx_net1.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_net1';   }"
        txtbx_add1.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_add1';   }"
        txtbx_billed1.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){   s.GetInputElement().name='txtbx_billed1';   }"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please highlight something on the content inside **Page_Load**. What all they do?

Comment: @Prabhat the codes inside Page_Load is for setting of text boxes name.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I cant comment so only I replied via answer. What said by Niranjan Kala is correct only.

In devexpress controls, we cant get/set the text box or any input control values from client side using the ID. So only DevExpress providing property called "ClientInstanceName". Using that we can set/get the values of input controls from client side.

Try like following,

```
<dx:ASPxButton ...>
<ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
    alert(txtbx_gross.GetValue());
}" />
```

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_gross" ClientInstanceName="txtbx_gross" runat="server"/>
```

**Updated Answer:**

**Cause:** It seems, If you change the value of server control through javascript in the client side it will not be propagated via postback in the serverside. and also It will be cleared if postback occurs.

**Solution:**
To resolve this postback problem, DevExpress has the technique called callback/ASPxCallbackPanel (like asp update panel).

So you should avoid the postback and use the callback techniques to implement your functionality . Try the following techniques,

**Solution 1:** *OnCallBack event on ComboBox Control*

**JS**

```
function SelectedIndexChanged(s, e) {           
        var selectedVal = FilterCombo.GetText();
        var gross = txtbx_gross.GetValue();
        var less = txtbx_less.GetValue();

        var str = gross + ":" + less + ":" + selectedVal;

        FilterCombo.PerformCallback(str);
    }
```

We can pass required parameters by concatenation with separator.

**.ASPx**

```
<dx:ASPxComboBox runat="server" ID="FilterCombo" ClientInstanceName="FilterCombo" Width="70px" DropDownWidth="70px" ValueType="System.Int32"
                            OnCallback="FilterCombo_Callback"  DropDownStyle="DropDownList" SelectedIndex="0">
                            <Items>
                                <dx:ListEditItem Value="3" />
                                <dx:ListEditItem Value="20" />
                                <dx:ListEditItem Value="25" />
                                <dx:ListEditItem Value="50" />
                            </Items>
                            <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
```

**Code behind:** : I'm not experienced with VB.Net. So i derived in asp.net with c#

```
protected void FilterCombo_Callback(object sender, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
        string[] paramlist = e.Parameter.Split(':');
        if (paramlist.Length > 0)
        {
            decimal gross = Convert.ToDecimal(paramlist[0].ToString());
            decimal less = Convert.ToDecimal(paramlist[1].ToString());
            string dropdown = paramlist[2].ToString();

            //Do your logic here
        }
    }
```

**Solution 2:** *Use the ASPxCallBackPanel control*

Same like above with some differences, Include the controls in the callback panel and do the callback instead of postback. Refer the following links,

1. [Callback Panel](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxMultiUseControlsDemos/CallbackPanel/Example.aspx)
2. [The Concept of Callbacks](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18387/the-concept-of-callbacks)

**Solution 3:** Still you have stuck with problem means, Just create the sample application with your problem and post it with question in Devexpress Forum if you have the licensed account.

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind giving me a sample based on my codes? Tried Niranjan answer but it's not working also the computation is not working too.

Comment: No, I just explained about ClientInstanceName property usage instead of using name to get/set the values to textbox.

Could you tell me When/How post back is occurs ? i.e. Button click event

Comment: post back occurs on my dropdown.

Comment: @x'tian I have updated my answer, try it. I hoe it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set control name/id property on Page_Load event. You can use the [ClientInstanceName](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridBase.ClientInstanceName.property) property. see below example:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ...>
    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {
        alert(txtDevExpress.GetText());
    }" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
<dx:ASPxTextBox ClientInstanceName="txtDevExpress">
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

Refer these:
[ASPxTextBox - getElementById vs ClientInstanceName](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q437638/aspxtextbox-getelementbyid-vs-clientinstancename)
[How to use ASPxTextBox client-side API / ClientIDMode="Static"](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q326949/how-to-use-aspxtextbox-client-side-api-clientidmode-static)
[How to use the ClientInstanceName and Name properties when they contain special characters](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18687/how-to-use-the-clientinstancename-and-name-properties-when-they-contain-special-characters)

Comment: Not working. When I try to inspect the elements the textbox name become  name="ctl00$MainContent$txtbx_gross" instead of "txtbx_gross".

Comment: Are you sure it is `<dx:ASPxTextBox ...>` & not `<asp:TextBox ...>`? I already mentioned on previous question that `ClientInstanceName` should be used for client-side events, but `ctl00$...$...` is a autogenerated client ID that only exist for standard ASP.NET controls, not DX ones.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto, Yes I'm sure its <dx:ASPxTextBox ...>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228372/retain-textbox-value-when-checkbox-is-checked), the `ClientInstanceName` attribute should be used for DevExpress controls' client-side events.

However, regarding the control ID naming which shown as `ctl00$[placeholder_name]$[control_name]`, this is explanation I got from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs):

> As we discussed, the ctl00 portion of the rendered id attribute
>   constitutes the ID value of the master page, but you may be wondering
>   how this ID value came about. We did not specify it anywhere in our
>   master or content page. Most server controls in an ASP.NET page are
>   added explicitly through the page's declarative markup.
>
> Other controls, like the master page itself, are not defined in the
>   declarative markup. Consequently, their ID values must be
>   automatically generated for us. The ASP.NET engine sets the ID values
>   at runtime for those controls whose IDs have not been explicitly set.
>   It uses the naming pattern ctlXX, where XX is a sequentially
>   increasing integer value.

Hence, since you're using `asp:Content` placeholder with master page as naming container, the controls inside it have their `id` attribute altered, even it is a DevExpress control.

To prevent this behavior, you need to define `ClientIDMode="Static"` as Niranjan Kala mentioned in his post, but this time used for [**master page level**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114040/how-to-disable-override-naming-containers-id-generation-of-content-pages-contr):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" 
    ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

Also set the same parameter in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Additionally, regarding textbox values which lost after postback issue, I found that you're using `MaskSettings` with a decimal point, but not specifying `IncludeLiterals`:

```
<%-- missing IncludeLiterals in MaskSettings --%>
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_add" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material" ClientInstanceName="txtbx_add">
   <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" AllowMouseWheel="false"/>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

The correct usage is shown below:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txtbx_add" runat="server" Width="170px" Theme="Material" ClientInstanceName="txtbx_add">
   <MaskSettings Mask="<0..99999g>.<00..99>" IncludeLiterals="DecimalSymbol" AllowMouseWheel="false" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

NB: You can use `IncludeLiterals="None"` if `DecimalSymbol` doesn't work.

Reference:

[ASPxTextBox does not persist its value on a postback if MaskSettings.Mask contains a dot](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T120091/aspxtextbox-does-not-persist-its-value-on-a-postback-if-masksettings-mask-contains-a-dot)

Comment: Did all your suggestion buddy. Still no luck. :( Even the IncludeLiterals. It's still losing its values. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: Have you missed something important at this point? I think your problem is wider than setting static `ClientID` & using `IncludeLiterals` for all textboxes. Provide every supporting details during postback items to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: My postback is triggered on my combobox.